# mysql: может ли у поля с типом varchar быть primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно создать таблицу, в которой буду хранить хеши объектов (товары, заказы и т.д.)

насколькоя  понимаю, то в таблице могут быть только 2 поля:

```
entity_id - primary
hash - varchar, not null, len 255
```

Вопрос в том, что entity_id может быть не числовым, поэтому скорее всего ему нужно задать тип varchar. Можно ли так делать?

Или как лучше сделать, чтобы потом поиск по этой таблице работал быстро? 
Размер таблицы будет примерно 500 тыс записей, нужно часто искать в ней, и изменять хеши (итогда нужно будет и удалять записи, но это редко).

Помогите пожалуйста правильно спроектировать таблицу.

Comment: Все эти вопросы вы можете проверить самостоятельно. Сложностей никаких нет. Индексировать числовые столбцы дешевле, чем строковые (во всяком случае так когда то было)

Comment: Делайте PK varchar и ни о чем не беспокойтесь. Конечно при условии, что львиная доля поисков идет именно по этому полю

Answer (score 1):

Чем меньше значения в индексе, тем меньше сам индекс. Маленький индекс занимает меньше памяти и поиск по нему обычно быстрее. Varchar(255) требует гораздо больше места, чем unsigned int ([storage requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-innodb)) и строить по нему индекс -- плохая затея.

Для идентификации записей в mysql обычно используют автоинкементирующийся суррогатный id (то есть, он не имеет отношения к самим данным и служит только для идентифкации). Такой идентификатор очень удобен, когда надо работать с записями, которые были предварительно получены из бд. Например, мы поискали в базе и теперь хотим обновить или удалить несколько записей, благодаря id доступ к ним будет довольно быстрый.

Но что если требуется искать по varchar? Строить индекс по нему не лучшая затея. Но только если это не *хеш-индекс* для поиска по поному совпадению. В InnoDB хеш-индексы не поддерживаются (если не ошибаюсь), но можно приделать костыль в виде поля содержащего хэш значения от того, по которому нужен поиск. К `entity_id` добавляете `entity_id_crc` и при записи туда кладёте `crc32(entity_id)` (обратите внимание, что функция crc32 возвращает unsigned int, значит колонка должна иметь именно этот тип). По такой колонке можно создать неуникальный индекс и при поиске писать `where entity_id_crc=crc32('foobar') and entity_id='foobar'` (так как поле entity_id_crc не уникально, то обязательно надо добавлять и проверку основного поля, но благодаря индексу такая проверка будет выполняться только для нескольких значений, а не всех записей в таблице).

Таким образом вам следует завести `id int unsigned not null autoicrement`, который будет первичным ключом. Операции по изменению и удалению записей можно производить по этому идентификатору (`where id=123`, `where id in (123, 456)`).
Для поиска нужно построить индекс по тем полям, которые будут участвовать в выражении `where` (возможно не всем, а только наиболее *селективным*). При этом следует избегать *b-tree индексов* по текстовым полям (они вряд ли будут полезны). Если искать по текстовым полям всё-таки надо (речь о полном совпадении `entity_id = 'foobar'`), то можно построить хеш-индекс (или если ваша подсистема хранения не поддерживает его, воспользоваться костылём описанным выше).

Comment: Надеюсь никто не послушает этого совета... Таблицы InnoDB являются кластаризованными по первичному ключу. Это означает, что отдельного индекса для первичного ключа не существует. Индекс первичного ключа в InnoDB это и есть сама таблица, в листьях b-tree лежат сами данные. Причем ключ лежит только один раз и для целей поиска и как данные. По этой причине поиск по первичному ключу всегда быстрее, чем по любому вторичному индексу. Так как при поиске по вторичному индексу сначала ищут по нему, а потом по первичному. Если основная масса поисков идет именно по varchar entity_id - то он лучший PK

Comment: @Mike интересное мнение насчёт лучшего PK. Мне кажется работа с таким PK будет не самой быстрой. Но я попробую проверить эту идею.

Comment: И да, никаких хеш индексов в MySQL нет и поиск по обычным b-tree индексам, построенным по varchar полям работает конечно несколько медленнее, чем по int, но это чисто из за необходимости сравнения в узлах более длинных строк (и общего объема индекса). Если строки скажем байт 100 длиной то по сравнению с int заметно падение скорости % на 30.

Comment: Правда если строка длинная, то есть другая проблема - во всех вторичных индексах для адресации записи используется сам первичный ключ. А следовательно при росте длины ключа, растут в объемах все вторичные индексы. И на таблицах где их много это может оказаться  серьезной проблемой